# Spring Security Oauth2 : invalid redirect url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2, spring-webflux

I am running a spring boot application  behind an Apache as a Reverse Proxy.
I'am using spring security oauth2, and I have faced this stack:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2AuthenticationException: [invalid_redirect_uri_parameter] 
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.authentication.OAuth2LoginReactiveAuthenticationManager.lambda$null$1(OAuth2LoginReactiveAuthenticationManager.java:93) ~[spring-security-oauth2-client-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorMap$23(Mono.java:3062) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.lambda$onErrorResume$25(Mono.java:3152) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnErrorResume$ResumeSubscriber.onError(FluxOnErrorResume.java:88) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators.error(Operators.java:181) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:48) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:442) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:114) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:55) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMap$MapConditionalSubscriber.onNext(FluxMap.java:213) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.onNext(MonoProcessor.java:389) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.drain(FluxConcatMap.java:422) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap$ConcatMapImmediate.onSubscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:212) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxConcatMap.subscribe(FluxConcatMap.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeek.subscribe(MonoPeek.java:71) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.add(MonoProcessor.java:531) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoProcessor.subscribe(MonoProcessor.java:444) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMap.subscribe(MonoMap.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoHandle.subscribe(MonoHandle.java:43) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterFuseable.java:113) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2071) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:78) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2073) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.set(Operators.java:1879) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MultiSubscriptionSubscriber.onSubscribe(Operators.java:1753) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onComplete(MonoNext.java:96) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter$FilterSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilter.java:160) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.checkTerminated(FluxFlatMap.java:825) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drainLoop(FluxFlatMap.java:591) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.drain(FluxFlatMap.java:571) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(FluxFlatMap.java:457) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:265) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:366) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFlatMap.subscribe(FluxFlatMap.java:97) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilter.subscribe(FluxFilter.java:53) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilter.subscribe(MonoFilter.java:46) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen$ThenIgnoreMain.drain(MonoIgnoreThen.java:172) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoIgnoreThen.subscribe(MonoIgnoreThen.java:56) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onComplete(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:75) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onComplete(MonoFlatMap.java:174) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxMapFuseable.java:144) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onComplete(FluxFilterFuseable.java:166) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$ScalarSubscription.request(Operators.java:2073) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxFilterFuseable.java:185) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.request(FluxMapFuseable.java:162) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onSubscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:103) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxMapFuseable.java:90) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterFuseable$FilterFuseableSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterFuseable.java:82) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoJust.subscribe(MonoJust.java:54) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFilterFuseable.subscribe(MonoFilterFuseable.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSubscriberContext.subscribe(MonoSubscriberContext.java:47) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxMapFuseable$MapFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxMapFuseable.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapInner.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:241) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Operators$MonoSubscriber.complete(Operators.java:1515) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onComplete(MonoCollectList.java:121) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.fastPath(FluxIterable.java:333) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:198) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList$MonoCollectListSubscriber.onSubscribe(MonoCollectList.java:72) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoCollectList.subscribe(MonoCollectList.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap$FlatMapMain.onNext(MonoFlatMap.java:150) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxSwitchIfEmpty$SwitchIfEmptySubscriber.onNext(FluxSwitchIfEmpty.java:67) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext$NextSubscriber.onNext(MonoNext.java:76) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.drain(FluxFilterWhen.java:295) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onNext(FluxFilterWhen.java:134) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.slowPath(FluxIterable.java:243) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable$IterableSubscription.request(FluxIterable.java:201) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen$FluxFilterWhenSubscriber.onSubscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:194) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:139) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxIterable.subscribe(FluxIterable.java:63) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.FluxFilterWhen.subscribe(FluxFilterWhen.java:69) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoNext.subscribe(MonoNext.java:40) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoSwitchIfEmpty.subscribe(MonoSwitchIfEmpty.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoMapFuseable.subscribe(MonoMapFuseable.java:59) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMap.subscribe(MonoFlatMap.java:60) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoDefer.subscribe(MonoDefer.java:52) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoPeekTerminal.subscribe(MonoPeekTerminal.java:61) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.MonoOnErrorResume.subscribe(MonoOnErrorResume.java:44) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
    at reactor.core.publisher.Mono.subscribe(Mono.java:3858) ~[reactor-core-3.2.12.RELEASE.jar:3.2.12.RELEASE]
```

After debugging I found that spring is rendering the a wrong redirect_uri in ServerOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationTokenConverte:
So instead of returning :
`http://example.com/login/oauth2/code/xxx // my domain name`

I got :

`http://localhost:8080/login/oauth2/code/xxx // the local host of the application`

```
//org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.web.server.ServerOAuth2AuthorizationCodeAuthenticationTokenConverter

private static OAuth2AuthorizationResponse convertResponse(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> queryParams = exchange.getRequest()
                .getQueryParams();
        String redirectUri = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUri(exchange.getRequest().getURI())
                .query(null)
                .build()
                .toUriString();

//redirectUri is htpp://localhost:8080/xxx !!

        return OAuth2AuthorizationResponseUtils
                .convert(queryParams, redirectUri);
    }
```

I have also set

```
server:
  use-forward-headers: true
```

but nothing has changed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `spring-security-oauth2-client`on your classpath you can modify the redirect uri with the property

```
spring.security.oauth2.client.registration.<your Client>.redirect-uri-template=https://my-redirect-uri.com
```

Source: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-security.html

Comment: After getting the authorisation code, spring try to validate this code by comparing the redirect_uri sending in the request and the one in the response.
So when he try to generate the redirect_uri in the response, I got this error, and  the redirect-uri-template is already configured.